# Reusing attachments in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am having a model `OutInvoice` which stores an attachment in an attribute `physical_copy`. Things work fine as per Rails standard.

Now I want to reuse this attachment (or a copy of this -> doesn't matter as long as deletion of the partner record doesn't delete the attachment but it stays connected to the partner and the new record separtely) in `InInvoice.physical_copy`

so something like

`in_invoice.update!(physical_copy: out_invoice.physical_copy)`

I tried the following inside the rails model but it fails with "ArgumentError in Home::InvoicesController#freeze - Could not find or build blob: expected attachable":

```
...
in_invoice.save!
in_invoice.physical_copy.attach(the_physical_out_invoice)
...

def the_physical_out_invoice
  physical_copy.attachment
end
```

Would be great to get coding support on how to reuse this Rails attachment in another model.

PS: I am using Rails 6.0.3 and Ruby 2.6.6

Comment: Try to change `physical_copy.attachment` to `physical_copy.blob`

Answer (score 1):

Says you have model `User` with `has_one_attached :avatar`

You can just attach from one record to another as copy. Be careful, if you delete attachment in one record, it will be unavailable in another

```
user_second.avatar.attach(user_first.avatar.blob)

user_second.avatar.blob.id == user_first.avatar.blob.id
# true
```

To create separate copy you need to read the file and attach it as new attachment. This way attachments are different

```
user_second.avatar.attach(io: StringIO.new(user_first.avatar.download), filename: user_first.avatar.filename)

user_second.avatar.blob.id == user_first.avatar.blob.id
# false
```

Comment: getting "no implicit conversion of Hash into String". Attached is a PDF

Comment: but this is supposed to work with any type of attachment. So ignore my second part :-)

Comment: sorry...should have posted

I tried to execute your message to 100%. it is in scope of the out_invoice (the partner object if you want in/out)

```in_invoice.physical_copy.attach(io: StringIO.new(physical_copy.download, filename: pdf_filename))```

Comment: that was the issue! A friend also pointed out via E-Mail :-)


It works! Upvoted but dont have enough reputation for this to counted